# Swift reverse nil-coalescenting operator?

Tags: swift

Swift has the nil-coalescing operator `a ?? b` which is shorthand for `a != nil ? a : b`. Does Swift have the opposite operator, a shorthand for `a == nil ? a : b` or in other words, `a == nil ? nil : b`?

I would use it to map an optional value to something else, like so:

```
let x = dict["key"] != nil ? mapValue(dict["key"]) : nil
// ideally: let x = dict["key"] ¿¿ mapValue(dict["key"])
```

Comment: Is `Optional.map()` what you are looking for? `let x = dict["key"].map { mapValue($0) }` or just `let  x = dict["key"].map(mapValue)`

Comment: @MartinR Indeed it is, thank you! You should post that as an answer, I would like to leave this question up for others since I had issues finding that myself. Coming from Python and JavaScript, they both use the "and" operator for this: `x = d["a"] && mapValue(d["a"])` and thus I was set on finding an operator and a method on `Optional` didn't even cross my mind.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`dict["key"]` returns an optional, and you want to map that value to another value if it is present, or get `nil` otherwise. That is exactly what [`Optional.map()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optional/1539476-map) is for:

> Evaluates the given closure when this `Optional` instance is not `nil`, passing the unwrapped value as a parameter.

In your case:

```
let x = dict["key"].map { mapValue($0) }
```

or simply

```
let x = dict["key"].map(mapValue)
```

This also has the advantage over

```
let x = dict["key"] != nil ? mapValue(dict["key"]) : nil
// or the hypothetical
let x = dict["key"] ¿¿ mapValue(dict["key"])
```

that `dict["key"]` is evaluated only once, not twice.

Comment: *"This also has the advantage over that `dict["key"]` is evaluated only once, not twice"* this is a good point and a mistake I've probably made in other languages without even realizing. Thank you, not just for the Swift answer but for a more generic lesson too.